# pass Python str to C function

Tags: python, c, string, pointers

I have `libx.so`, and it exports a function and a global `char *`,

```
char *c_ptr = 0;

void foo(char *s)
{
    c_ptr = s;
}
```

In python, I pass a `str` to `foo` in 2 ways,

```
>>>libx = ctypes.CDLL("./libx.so")
#pass a raw str
>>>libx.foo("string")

#pass a c_char_p object
>>>libx.foo(c_char_p("strng"))
```

**Q**

1.I think, `libx.foo("string")` passes a Python `str` object to a C function which will later assign the string to `char *c_ptr`. I wonder, will `c_ptr` points to the `str` object `"string"` after the call `foo`? Cuz I presume the `str` object `"string"` will be garbage-collected after the call to `foo`, right?

2.Are the 2 ways (passing `"string"` and `c_char_p("string")`) difference in effect?
Are they different in effect?

Comment: "Will that work"? Well, yes, presumably copying a local variable to a global variable will work. A separate and entirely unrelated question is whether the pointer will still point to something valid later on.

Comment: @KerrekSB, well, you mean I should not just simply assign `s` to `c_ptr` in `foo`, but **copy** the string pointed by `s`?

Comment: I mean that you should ask a better question. "Will it work", or "it doesn't work", are far too unspecific. You're a technical person, so write a technical question :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB, so a Python `str` object passed to a C function will only be valid during the call to that C function, if the function finishes, the `str` object is no longer there, right?

Comment: Well, that would be the right question to ask! I don't know Python very well, and I too an curious to see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1: What is Happening

ctypes does adapt the Python string, correctly guessing that the function takes a `char*`.  Effectively, `libx.foo("string")` is equivalent to the second example `libx.foo(c_char_p("string"))` with a little runtime adaptation.

Your intuition about the string being garbage collected shortly after the call is correct.  Nothing in Python retains a reference to the adapted c_char_p view of the string, and thus it will be returned to the object pool — likely to be re-issued in the future.  Which means that the `char* c_ptr` will probably point at junk very soon.

## 2: Different in Effect

The second form allows you to keep a reference to the view passed to the C function.  If you changed the example slightly:

```
>>> s = c_char_p("string")
>>> libx.foo(s)
```

Then as long as a reference is maintained to `s`, the `c_ptr` value will be valid.  You could accomplish that by just keeping a reference in the module implementing your binding to libx.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who finds this, in Python 3 string and bytes are now different. ctypes needs a bytes instance in order to correctly pass the parameter as `char*`.

`test_lib.get_val(b'Test1', byref(a))` will pass the full 'Test1' as a char* to the c function

`test_lib.get_val('Test1', byref(a))` will not pass 'Test1' as a char*, from my little bit of testing it passes the first letter of the python `str` followed by a null charcter.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to the answer by Keenan Kugler,
another code seems to work for Python 3.x users to deliver string text to callee C function, when dynamic text value is being handled:

```
text = input("Text:")
test_lib.get_val(bytes(text, encoding='utf-8')
```